# How to find inverse of a relation if the inverse isn't a function?

Tags: functions, relations, inverse-function

I am trying to find the inverse of the following function $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(a)=\frac{(-1)^a(2a-1)+1}{4}$.

I switched $x$ and $y$ and then tried solving for $y$. This is the technique that everyone learned back in middle school/high school. However, since the inverse relation isn't a function, it is not possible. How do I find the inverse using a different method?

Comment: There’s always an inverse *relation*, as subset of, in this case, $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: As a function defined on $\Bbb Z^{>0}$, this looks perfectly one-to-one and onto to me. There should not be any problem at all. Have you written out the values for inputs from (say) $1$ through $12$?

Answer (score 2):

Here, the inverse function exists :

$$g(x)=2n$$ for $n>0$ and $$g(x)=-2n+1$$ for $n\le 0$

$f$ is actually a function from $\mathbb Z^+$ to $\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ acts on $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ as follows:
$$ f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{n}{2} &\text{if}& n\equiv 0\pmod{2}\\-\frac{n-1}{2}&\text{if}&n\equiv 1\pmod{2} \end{array}\right.$$
hence $f^{-1}$ maps positive integers into even numbers and non-positive integers into odd numbers:
$$ f^{-1}(m) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}2m &\text{if}& m>0\\1-2m&\text{if}&m\leq 0. \end{array}\right.$$